# Get/generate shared link for a uploaded file in Google Drive API v3

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

I am uploading files to a Gdrive follow [this](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads#resumable) instructions. In the [File](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/) objtect I just set the name, like this:

```
{
 "name": "myObjectName"
}
```

The files are uploading without problem. Now I need to generate a shared link for each upload file, Do you know who is the request that I have to do?

Thanks,

Comment: please include your code and not a link to a tutorial this tutorial location may change in the future without it your question would be of no help to others.  You should always include the code in your questions.

Comment: @DaImTo I included my code, including the fix, in an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume that you are using Drive API v3. To set up permissions after uploading the file you have to use the method [`create`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create). You can check the [sharing documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-sharing) to know more about the different ways of creation of permissions and its different levels of access. After sharing the file, you can retrieve the link with the property [`webViewLink`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files#resource-representations) of the file. If you still have any doubts, please ask me for further clarification.

Answer (score 1):

With @Jacques-Guzel Heron´s help, I completed the upload file process. I created a wrapper for Google Drive API v3. That is my code if any need to do something like that: (I am using C#):

```
public interface IGDriveApiV3Wrapper
{
    string UploadFile(string filePath, string gDriveUploadDestinationFolderId = null);

    bool SetFilePermissions(string fileId, GDriveFileRole gDriveRole, GDriveFileType gDriveType);

    GDriveFile GetFileInfo(string fileId);
}
```

---

```
public class GDriveApiV3NativeWrapper : IGDriveApiV3Wrapper
{
    private const string GDriveFilesApiResumablePath = "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=resumable";

    private const string GDriveTokenApiPath = "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token";

    private static readonly HttpClient GDriveClient = new HttpClient { Timeout = Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan };

    private readonly List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> _getTokenRequestContent;

    private static GDriveTokenInfo _gDriveTokenInfo;

    private static readonly object UpdateGDriveTokenInfoLocker = new object();

    public GDriveApiV3NativeWrapper(string gDriveApiClientId, string gDriveApiClientSecret, string gDriveApiRefreshToken)
    {
        _getTokenRequestContent = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", gDriveApiClientId),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", gDriveApiClientSecret),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("refresh_token", gDriveApiRefreshToken),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "refresh_token")
        };
    }

    public string UploadFile(string filePath, string gDriveUploadDestinationFolderId = null)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filePath))
            throw new ArgumentException("Value cannot be null or empty.", nameof(filePath));

        FileInfo fileInfo;
        try
        {
            fileInfo = new FileInfo(filePath);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("File not valid.", nameof(filePath), ex);
        }

        if (!fileInfo.Exists)
            throw new ArgumentException("File not exists.", nameof(filePath));

        using (var initiateResumableUploadSessionRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, GDriveFilesApiResumablePath))
        {
            UpdateGDriveTokenInfo();

            initiateResumableUploadSessionRequest.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(_gDriveTokenInfo.TokenType, _gDriveTokenInfo.AccessToken);

            var jsonContent = new JObject(
                new JProperty("name", fileInfo.Name));

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(gDriveUploadDestinationFolderId))
            {
                jsonContent.Add(new JProperty("parents", new JArray { gDriveUploadDestinationFolderId }));
            }

            initiateResumableUploadSessionRequest.Content = new StringContent(jsonContent.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            var initiateResumableUploadSessionResponse = GDriveClient.SendAsync(initiateResumableUploadSessionRequest).Result;

            if (initiateResumableUploadSessionResponse.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                throw new ExternalException(initiateResumableUploadSessionResponse.ToString());

            using (var uploadFileRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Put, initiateResumableUploadSessionResponse.Headers.Location))
            {
                uploadFileRequest.Content = new ByteArrayContent(File.ReadAllBytes(filePath));

                HttpResponseMessage uploadFileResponse;

                uploadFileResponse = GDriveClient.SendAsync(uploadFileRequest).Result;

                if (uploadFileResponse.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK && uploadFileResponse.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.Created)
                    throw new ExternalException(uploadFileResponse.ReasonPhrase);

                var uploadFileResponseBody = uploadFileResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                JObject uploadFileResponseJson = JObject.Parse(uploadFileResponseBody);

                return uploadFileResponseJson["id"].ToString();
            }
        }
    }

    public bool SetFilePermissions(string fileId, GDriveFileRole gDriveFileRole, GDriveFileType gDriveFileType)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileId))
            throw new ArgumentException("Value cannot be null or empty.", nameof(fileId));

        using (var setFilePermissionsRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, $"https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/{fileId}/permissions"))
        {
            UpdateGDriveTokenInfo();

            setFilePermissionsRequest.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(_gDriveTokenInfo.TokenType, _gDriveTokenInfo.AccessToken);

            var jsonContent2 = new JObject(
                new JProperty("role", gDriveFileRole.ToString().ToLower()),
                new JProperty("type", gDriveFileType.ToString().ToLower()));

            setFilePermissionsRequest.Content = new StringContent(jsonContent2.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            HttpResponseMessage setFilePermissionsResponse = GDriveClient.SendAsync(setFilePermissionsRequest).Result;

            if (setFilePermissionsResponse.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                throw new ExternalException(setFilePermissionsResponse.ToString());
        }

        return true;
    }

    public GDriveFile GetFileInfo(string fileId)
    {
        using (var getFileInfoRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, $"https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/{fileId}?fields=name,webViewLink"))
        {
            UpdateGDriveTokenInfo();

            getFileInfoRequest.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(_gDriveTokenInfo.TokenType, _gDriveTokenInfo.AccessToken);

            HttpResponseMessage getFileInfoResponse = GDriveClient.SendAsync(getFileInfoRequest).Result;

            if (getFileInfoResponse.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                throw new ExternalException(getFileInfoResponse.ToString());

            var getFileInfoResponseBody = getFileInfoResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

            JObject getFileInfoResponseJson = JObject.Parse(getFileInfoResponseBody);

            return new GDriveFile
            {
                Id = fileId,
                Name = getFileInfoResponseJson["name"].ToString(),
                WebViewLink = getFileInfoResponseJson["webViewLink"].ToString()
            };
        }
    }

    private void UpdateGDriveTokenInfo()
    {
        lock (UpdateGDriveTokenInfoLocker)
        {
            if (_gDriveTokenInfo != null && !_gDriveTokenInfo.IsExpired())
            {
                return;
            }

            using (var refreshTokenRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, GDriveTokenApiPath))
            {
                refreshTokenRequest.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(_getTokenRequestContent);

                var getTokenRequestResponse = GDriveClient.SendAsync(refreshTokenRequest).Result;

                var jsonResponse = JObject.Parse(getTokenRequestResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);

                _gDriveTokenInfo = new GDriveTokenInfo((string)jsonResponse["access_token"], (int)jsonResponse["expires_in"], (string)jsonResponse["token_type"]);
            }
        }
    }
```

---

```
public class GDriveFile
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string WebViewLink { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
public enum GDriveFileRole
{
    Owner,
    Organizer,
    FileOrganizer,
    Writer,
    Commenter,
    Reader
}
```

---

```
public enum GDriveFileType
{
    User,
    Group,
    Domain,
    Anyone
}
```

---

```
public class Program
{
    private static IGDriveApiV3Wrapper _gDriveApiV3Wrapper;

    private readonly string _gDriveUploadDestinationFolderId;

    public Program(IGDriveApiV3Wrapper gDriveApiV3Wrapper, string gDriveUploadDestinationFolderId = null)
    {
        _gDriveApiV3Wrapper = gDriveApiV3Wrapper;
        _gDriveUploadDestinationFolderId = gDriveUploadDestinationFolderId;
    }

    public string Upload(string filePath)
    {
            string fileId = _gDriveApiV3Wrapper.UploadFile(filePath, _gDriveUploadDestinationFolderId);

            _gDriveApiV3Wrapper.SetFilePermissions(fileId, GDriveFileRole.Reader, GDriveFileType.Anyone);

            GDriveFile gDriveFile = _gDriveApiV3Wrapper.GetFileInfo(fileId);

            return gDriveFile.WebViewLink;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Class GDrivenTokenInfo i don`t see its code

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).